# Change date format from 20140511 to DD-MM-YYYY SQL 2008

Tags: date, format

I have 2000+ rows returned with the query below but the date needs to be changed so it's more readable. Is there a way to convert the date from being returned as 20140511 to DD-MM-YYYY in the query below?

```
Select Jobname AS OptimiseJobs, RunDate AS Date 
from tablename 
where jobname like '%Optimise'
```

thanks!

Comment: It might be useful to add the brand of dbserver you're working on as a tag.

Comment: `SQL 2008` ? in your header or is it `sql-server 2008?`

Answer (score 0):

In sql-server

```
 Select Jobname AS OptimiseJobs, cast(RunDate as date) AS Date 
    from tablename 
    where jobname like '%Optimise'
```

[Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/17467)

Answer (score 0):

IF you are using SQL server then try below query:

```
SELECT Jobname AS OptimiseJobs,
CONVERT(varchar(20),CONVERT(date, CONVERT(varchar(8), RunDate), 112),105) AS Date
FROM tablename
WHERE jobname LIKE '%Optimise'
```

Comment: Thank you so much!! This has sorted it! :)